# Using std::set's .begin() and .end() function produces unexpected results

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have the following simple program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    unsigned int qwer = 6132;
    unsigned int ty = 3512;
    unsigned int vv = 4331;
    unsigned int gg = 1337;
    set<unsigned int> asdf = {};
    asdf.insert(qwer);
    asdf.insert(ty);
    asdf.insert(vv);
    asdf.insert(gg);
    cout << "&asdf.begin() = " << &asdf.begin();
    unsigned int setint = *asdf.begin();
    cout << "\nsetint = " << setint;
    setint = *asdf.end();
    cout << "\nsetint = " << setint;
    cout << "\n&asdf.end() = " << &asdf.end();
    return 0;
}
```

It produces this output:

```
&asdf.begin() = 0x22fe08
setint = 1337
setint = 4
&asdf.end() = 0x22fe08
```

Why does the address of `asdf.begin()` and `asdf.end()` match? I'd assume they'd have distinct addresses pointing to distinct values? And although their addresses do match, the values pointed to do not! Why is this?

EDIT: Also why does setint = asdf.end() appear to set setint's value to the amount of elements in the set rather than the last value in the set? (I'm assuming it should be 6132 right?)

Comment: you are actually printing the address of the value returned by those functions, thus something that is on your stack and that may be reused (and seems to be reused here to store both values).

Comment: Dereferencing `asdf.end()` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Copy the text from your output window and paste it into the question. Don't take a picture of it.

Comment: `&asdf.begin()` is ill-formed. The `&` operator cannot be applied to an rvalue  (unless it's an rvalue of class type which overloads `operator&`, which this likely isn't). If you don't see an error message then adjust your compiler settings because you're not doing C++ at the moment.

Comment: You can store the iterator begin inside the local variable and get its address to be printed out but that still be a different address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have lots of undefined behaviour.

```
&asdf.begin()
&asdf.end()
```

You are taking the address of prvalue. `&` can only be applied to lvalues and *qualified-id*s (things with names)

```
*asdf.end()
```

The `end` iterator is not dereferencable. It points to the "one-past-the-end" position.

Comment: The first two are ill-formed, (not UB per se).

Comment: @M.M Yeah, I was trying to paraphrase "The operand shall be an lvalue or a qualified-id."